# Show progress and wait until execution of exec() function in PHP

Tags: php

I have written a PHP script to execute a program using `exec()` function. It usually take 30 seconds to 5 minutes to execute the program, depends on the input given. During long time of program execution, the web page seems hang on (freeze). Can't able to determine the time for execution or whether the program is still running or terminated.

`exec("compile.exe -in data.csv -format 5 -out report.html");`

I tried to execute the program using `popen()` and `pclose()` function. It executes in background. Again, I can't able to determine the time for execution or whether the program is still running or terminated. But, the web page does not hang on.

`pclose(popen("start /B compile.exe -in data.csv -format 5 -out report.html", "r"));`

I just want to display a text message or image till successful program execution to show that the program is still running.

Comment: Can't you just have a animated preloader display prior to the exec code and set to hide at after the code executes and if it hangs the preloader would freeze?

Comment: the page is not loaded yet until script ends, use ajax for this kind of task and exec the binary in the ajax request, then the page will be loadead and you can update status of execution via javascript